# When should you use lineHeightMultiple vs. lineSpacing?

Tags: ios, uikit

There seem to be two different ways to explicitly set the line height of an attributed string in iOS. Which is the preferred method and why?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsmutableparagraphstyle/1524596-lineheightmultiple

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsmutableparagraphstyle/1524596-lineheightmultiple

Comment: Did you get your answer to this? If yes, please post. It will help me and other people to understand this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Line Spacing** is the distance in CGFloat between two lines.

**Line Height Multiple** the space between each line equal to the value multiply with the line height. Imagine Line Height Multiple = *number of new lines* for each line.

ie: `lineHeightMultiple = 2` will insert 2 `"\n"` and `lineHeightMultiple = 3` will insert `"\n"`.

Answer (score 19):

Note that there are subtle differences to using these parameters, even if you are effectively setting the same distances.

[image]

The above shows lineSpacing applied. When selecting text, the spacing is visible below the lines of text. The last spacing is truncated.

[image]

The above shows lineHeightMultiple applied. The selection shows the spacing is above the lines of text. The top spacing is NOT truncated.